# How to undo 'Exclude from Coverage Results'?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, dotcover, jetbrains-rider

I've excluded some functions from the coverage result by right-clicking them in the unit test coverage tree and picking "Exclude from Coverage Results".

Now I want them back. The [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/dotCover__Setting_up_Coverage_Filters.html#404203cb) suggests clicking the "**Show all nodes** link on top of the [Unit Tests Coverage window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Unit_Tests_Coverage_window.html)" but I cannot find such a beast anywhere. I've pored over the documentation, scrutinised every pixel of the UI and went through the settings with a fine-toothed comb, but to no avail ... I've also tried searching the project tree and `%AppData%/JetBrains/*` for the names of the excluded functions but could not find anything that looked relevant.

How can I un-exclude the excluded functions? I'm using Rider 2022.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updated Rider to version 2022.1.2. Now the coverage window has a bar that reads "Coverage tree has excluded nodes. Show all nodes" whenever there are excluded nodes, with "Show all nodes" being a link that does just what the documentation says ...

Comment: fwiw i'm using rider 2022.2.3 (linux) and i have no such option available in coverage window  (adding my solution to this problem below)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to undo it for me (rider 2022.2.3 linux) was to close/reopen solution.